# Why is P(A ∪ (B ∩ C)) = P(A) + P(A’ ∩ B ∩ C)?

Tags: probability

I need to calculate the probability of A ∪ (B ∩ C). P(A), P(B) and P(C) are given.

I first made A and (B ∩ C) mutually exclusive as follows:

```
P(A ∪ (B ∩ C))
= P(A ∩ B’ ∩ C’) + P(A’ ∩ B ∩ C)
```

In the solution they did the following though:

```
P(A ∪ (B ∩ C))
= P(A) + P(A’ ∩ B ∩ C)
```

Why is the "A'" included in the second event but there's no (B' ∩ C') in the first event?

Sorry if this is a silly question, I just started learning this and it's all new to me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Write a truth table for each:

$\begin{matrix}A & \vert & B & \vert & C & \vert & A \cup (B \cap C) & \vert & \begin{matrix}(A \cap B' \cap C') \cup \\ (A' \cap B \cap C)\end{matrix} & \vert & A\cup (A' \cap B \cap C) \\ \hline T & \vert & T & \vert & T & \vert & T & \vert & \color{red}F & \vert & T \\ T & \vert & T & \vert & F & \vert & T & \vert & \color{red}F & \vert & T \\ T & \vert & F & \vert & T & \vert & T & \vert & \color{red}F & \vert & T \\ T & \vert & F & \vert & F & \vert & T & \vert & T & \vert & T \\ F & \vert & T & \vert & T & \vert & T & \vert & T & \vert & T\\ F & \vert & T & \vert & F & \vert & F & \vert & F & \vert & F \\ F & \vert & F & \vert & T & \vert & F & \vert & F & \vert & F \\ F & \vert & F & \vert & F & \vert & F & \vert & F & \vert & F\end{matrix}$

Column 4 represents the original problem. Column 5 represents your solution. Note that they do not match very often. Column 6 represents the book's solution. It should be clear that $A$ and $A'$ are mutually exclusive. Additionally, $A'\cap B \cap C$ is a smaller set than $A'$, so it is still mutually exclusive with $A$.

Answer (score 0):

They use the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability), which says that for any events $A$ and $B$ we have that
$$
P(A)=P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap B'),
$$
where $A'$ is the complement of $A$. What they did in the solution is the following
\begin{align*}
P(A\cup(B\cap C))
&=P((A\cup(B\cap C))\cap A)+P((A\cup(B\cap C))\cap A')\\
&=P(A)+P(B\cap C\cap A')
\end{align*}
since $(A\cup(B\cap C))\cap A=A$ and $(A\cup(B\cap C))\cap A'=B\cap C\cap A'$.